# Unable to drop the image in a target location

Tags: javascript, html

I have written a simple code for drag and drop. lets have a look at the code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>System Drag and Drop Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        {
            function dragUser(user,oEvent)
            {
                oEvent.dataTransfer.setData('User',user.id)
            }
            function dropUser(target,oEvent)
            {
                var user= oEvent.dataTransfer.getData('User');
                alert(user);
                alert(target);
                target.appendChild(document.getElementById('user'));
                oEvent.returnValue=false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Try daragging this text to the red box</p>
<p>
    <div style="border: 1px solid black; width: 150px; height: 150px">
        <img id="img" src="mine,image,life,quote,words,message-5eb746364548d71d07c86e52e63b7b56_h.jpg" width="100px" height="100px" ondragstart="dragUser(this,event)">
    </div>

    <div id="div2" style="background-color: red; width: 100px; height: 100px; clear: both" ondrop="dropUser(this,event)" ondragenter="return false" ondragover="return false">

    </div>
</p>

</body>

</html>
```

The problem is that when i try to drag the image from the above div to the lower div with id="div2" than my image is not being dropped instead of it it opens in in a tab as an image.
please let me know the reason behind this.

Comment: Can you provide a live example?

Comment: Why is your JS wrapped in {}?

Comment: There is no id called user. You are making a reference to something that doesn't exist.

Comment: no i am using firefox

Comment: works with a correct id: http://jsfiddle.net/MY2Kp/